# Auto Enable Controller Service NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi, dataflow, hortonworks-dataflow

I have an ExecuteSQL processor, it was always disabled when the servers down or loss of power because the Controller Service of DBCP Connection Pool turned off, and I have to turn on the DBCP Connection Pool manually. Can I auto-enable that Controller Service?

Comment: Krismato Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting problem. The one of the possible resolutions is to use nifi-api. You should track your controller service status by sending http requests perdiodically. When the status changes to "enable", you should send put request to your processor with changed state "enable". About api you can read on official site.